# Collection view cell spacing and width issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using the collection to show the product images and name and I'm creating xib file for collection view cell.I want to show the rounded images and text and each row contain the 4 images in a row but it's not working for me showing me 5 cells in a row and three in another row also images is not rounding properly.I've used the sizeForItemAt function in shopViewController class for given the height and width.I know my calculation was wrong.I attached the screenshot please check thanks.
ShopViewController Class:

```
var products : [Products2] = [
        Products2(pImage:"login", name: "Men"),
        Products2(pImage:"login", name: "Men"),
        Products2(pImage:"login", name: "Men"),
        Products2(pImage:"login", name: "Men"),
        Products2(pImage:"login", name: "Men"),
        Products2(pImage:"login", name: "Men"),
        Products2(pImage:"login", name: "Men"),
        Products2(pImage:"login", name: "Men")
    ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing: ShopCollectionViewCell.self), bundle: .main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String(describing: ShopCollectionViewCell.self))
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
}

extension ShopViewControll:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return products.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        self.configureProductCell(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
    }
    
    
    func configureProductCell(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: ShopCollectionViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? ShopCollectionViewCell else {return UICollectionViewCell()}
        cell.productData = self.products[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (self.collectionView.bounds.width / 3) - 10
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 150)
    }
```

ShopCollectionView Cell using XIB FIle:

```
var productData: Products2? = nil{
        didSet{
            if let product = productData{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   
                    self.proImage.image = UIImage(named:product.pImage)
                    self.lblName.text = product.name
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        proImage.layer.cornerRadius = proImage.frame.size.height / 2 
    }
```

ShopViewcontroller Class constraints:
[image]

ShopViewCell Class using   constraints:
[image]

Result Screenshot:

[image]

I want to achieve this result

[image]

Comment: check your cell width with number of items and each width /height. You width is less compare to height or height is less compare to width. to make items rounded, both need to be same.

Comment: try this: 
let itemWidth = CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width / 4) - collectionView.minimumInteritemSpacing, height: 150)
in your delegate sizeForItemAt function.

I believe you're not respecting the minimumInteritemSpacing value of collectionView while calculating itemSize

Comment: Alexander Borisov when i'm trying your code in sizeforItemAt function it throws an error (Value of type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'minimumInteritemSpacing')